# How to return data from a subscription to HttpClient

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm implementing search and trying to use async pipe and http client. How should I return the observable from the service as an array of Definitions? The service uses HttpClient to fetch some data, I need to map it to a list of Definitions. Quiet confused with rxjs, should I pipe and map, or return data in the subscription function or return the observable?

```
export class DefinitionService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      searchTerm(term: string) {
          return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/search?term=abc')
                  .subscribe((data: string) => {
                    // Data extraction from the HTTP response is already done
                    // Display the result
                    console.log('TJ user data', data);
                  });
      }
    }
```

Code to handle search with rxjs operators in component:

```
searchInput = new FormControl();

constructor(private definitionService: DefinitionService) {
  this.definitions = this.searchInput.valueChanges
                      .pipe(
                        startWith(''),
                        debounceTime(500),
                        distinctUntilChanged(),
                        switchMap(value => this.definitionService.searchTerm(value))
                      )
}
```

Template:

```
<input class="format-input-button"
        (click)="clickInput()"
        [formControl]="searchInput">

<div class="format-options">
  <div *ngFor="let definition of definitions" class="search-result" (click)="selectResult('test result')">
    <div>{{definition.name}}</div>
    <div>{{definition.description}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could I do something like this?

```
searchTerm(term: string) {
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/search?term=abc')
              .pipe(
                map(result => {
                  // do mapping here
                  return mappedData;
                })
              );
  }
```

Someone suggested using async pipe, should I use it on the search result Observable? Do I still need switchMap if I use async pipe?

Comment: What is the structure of *your* definition? Also, share the structure of your data...

Comment: You should also show any template code too. Perhaps this will help... https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#async-pipe

Comment: @JGFMK do I need switchMap if I'm using async pipe? that guide says it returns the latest result of an observable like what switchMap does

Comment: The async pipe is typically used on variables in your code that are/return an `Observable` or a `Promise` - check out the [`AsyncPipe` docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) for more info.

Comment: And by the way, you should handle subscribing in the code that _calls_ that particular method, not _in the method_ itself as returning an `Observable` that you called subscribed on will actually return a [`Subscription`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscription).

Comment: i think I'll delete this question and ask another